# Why is the aux indicator on my HVAC system lighting up when A/C is called for?

Tags: wiring, hvac, thermostat, heating, air-conditioning

HVAC novice. New professionally installed heat pump (Goodman) and air handler. Old thermostat from the early 90’s. No aux heater installed. My assumption is the landlord wanted to save money and in CA if the pump stops working in the winter, we’ll survive.

I want to replace the thermostat (haven’t done it yet).

All wires appear to be wired correctly at the thermostat, except for two wires that run from the thermostat to the air handler. The W2 and the O/B. At the thermostat, the two wires are separate but once inside the air handler, the two wires are twisted together and tied into the reversing valve wire with a wire nut. From there the harness leads up to the pump (I assume, as the wire disappears into the ceiling and the pump is mounted on the roof).

When the ac is selected on the thermostat, it works but the AUX indicator lights up. When the heater is selected, it works but the AUX indicator goes out.

Why would they tie the two together? Or is it possible that they made an error? I have the wiring diagram, and from what I can tell, it doesn’t mention tying those together.

Comment: If I was renting, I would never consider replacing the thermostat myself.

Comment: I agree 100% with @Mattman944 here.  Keep in mind that is ANYTHING goes wrong here and it's discovered that you changed out the thermostat and possibly the wiring they may attempt to hold you liable for damages.  If you really want a different thermostat, you might ask the landlord to change it out.  You might also offer to pay for it.  Otherwise, don't mess with it!